# ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, android-view

```
    val rvMaps = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvMaps)
    // Set layout manager on the recycler
    rvMaps.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Well  based on your error, your `rvMaps` is `ConstraintLayout`, and you are referencing it as a `RecyclerView`, you might wanna check your `xml` if you are really referencing the correct `.id`, or perhaps post your `xml` so we can see it

Comment: Your error clearly shows that you are providing the wrong references here. I think you should check your `xml` file `id` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorrry now it's fine I gave the Constraint Layout the id rvMaps and not the recyclerview